# How to make threads in java to run in order 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 etc

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a task where I have 3 threads: Wax, Polish and Wash.
I must to make program to run in order waxed -> polished -> washed -> waxed -> polished -> washed etc.

Here is my code

```
package konsumencitest;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class Car {
    public boolean waxOn = false;

    public synchronized void waxed() {
        waxOn = true;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void polished() {
        waxOn = false;
        notifyAll();
    }

        public synchronized void washed() {
        waxOn = false;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void waitForWaxing() throws InterruptedException {
        while (waxOn = false) {
            wait();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void waitForPolishing() throws InterruptedException {
        while (waxOn = true) {
            wait();
        }
    }

        public synchronized void waitForWashing() throws InterruptedException {
        while (waxOn = true) {
            wait();
        }
    }
}

class Wax implements Runnable {
    private Car car;

    public Wax(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                System.out.print("Waxed!");
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);
                car.waxed();
                car.waitForPolishing();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Existing via interrupt");
        }
        System.out.println("Ending Wax on task");
    }
}

class Polish implements Runnable {
    private Car car;

    public Polish(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                car.waitForWaxing();
                System.out.print("Polished!");
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);
                car.polished();
                                car.waitForWashing();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Exiting via interrupt");
        }
        System.out.println("Ending Wax off task");
    }
}

class Wash implements Runnable {
    private Car car;

    public Wash(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                car.waitForWaxing();
                System.out.print("Washed!");
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);
                car.washed();
                                car.waitForWaxing();


            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Exiting via interrupt");
        }
        System.out.println("Ending Wax off task");
    }
}

public class WaxOMatic {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Car car = new Car();
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        service.execute(new Wax(car));
        service.execute(new Polish(car));
                service.execute(new Wash(car));
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        service.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

but the output is "Waxed!Polished!Washed!Washed!Washed!Washed!Washed!Washed!Washed!Washed!Washed!Washed!Washed!Washed!Washed!Washed!Washed!Washed! etc.".

How to fix it?

Comment: `while (waxOn = true) {...` is wrong. It should be `while(waxOn) {...` The same with the others loops.

Comment: it's not the same?

Comment: waxOn = true assigns waxOn to true, you probably meant waxOn == true which is equivalent to while(waxOn)

Comment: I changed it but now the output is: "Waxed!Polished!Washed!Washed!Polished!Waxed!Washed!Polished!Waxed!Washed!Polished!Polished!Washed!Waxed!Washed!Polished!Waxed!".  It's still wrong.

Comment: This problem doesn't make much sense: if only one thread is allowed to work at once, you'll be faster, and the code will be much simpler, by using a single thread doing all the work.

Comment: It must work with 3 threads.

Comment: On Car class, yhy are you using a single variable waxOn to wait for washing, polishing and washing? Should not be one variable for each state?

Comment: @AdrianMazurkiewicz Why must it work with three threads.  Your problem does not resemble any of the problems that threads were meant to solve.  If you want your program to do certain things in a certain order, the _best_ way to do it is to do those things in a single thread.

Comment: @marcellorvalle it must work on 3 threads, It is not required only one variable.